# How give Cloud Shell only access in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I want to grant access to a GCP account which limits the ability to create resources via the console UI and cloud shell must be used for any resource creation.

Comment: You want to disallow the console access and let only the command line (through Cloud Shell or elsewhere) active to manage resources, right?

Comment: This is correct. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Perhaps give a physical user project viewer only, with that he/she can only view the UI . Use a service account with editor role and have the physical user use service account impersonation to build resources.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restrict users from making changes or creating / deleting resources using GCP's cloud console and allow full access using command line at the same time.

However - solution [offered by @dany L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332084/how-give-cloud-shell-only-access-in-gcp#comment124331750_70332084) seems a good one - restricting actual user's access to "viewer" role and granting him ability to [impersonate a single service account](http://Restricting%20actual%20user%27s%20access%20to%20%22viewer%22%20role%20and%20granting%20him%20a%20role%20for%20impersonating%20a%20single%20service%20account) seems a viable workarond.

Comment: It's not a workaround, impersonation is the only way!!!

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Shell uses the identity logged into Google Accounts for authorization. To use different permissions (roles) requires using different identities. Google Cloud IAM does not differentiate between a user using the GUI and a user using Cloud Shell.